# Least-square fit with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, linear-regression, least-squares

I would like to solve a [least-square optimization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) using Google Script.

Is there a way to solve such mathematical optimization problems with Google Apps Script? Are there APIs or services to connect to that solve such much advanced math problems?

Answer (score 0):

There qre no builtin services in gas that do that.
Write the js code or find a js library that does it.